# Minecraft/Xbox Live not working when Content Restrictions are enabled

Tags: ios, ipad, screen-time

We recently had to enable Content Restrictions on my son's iPad, but now he cannot sign in to his Xbox Live account in Minecraft.

The iPad is currently running iOS version 12.3.1

In the Settings app on the iPad I go into 'Screen Time -> Content & Privacy Restrictions -> Content Restrictions -> Web Content'

We set the Web Content to 'Allowed Websites Only'

But now when we go into Minecraft on the iPad and try to sign in to the Xbox Live account we get the message "Sorry, something went wrong. Give it another try, or try on Xbox.com"

If we change the Web Content setting to 'Unrestricted Access', or 'Limit Adult Websites', Minecraft allows us to sign into Xbox Live.

We have tried adding https://xbox.com to the list of allowed websites, but that isn't working. What address/domain do we need to list that will allow Minecraft/Xbox Live to work within iOS content restrictions?

FYI - I've tried posting this question on Microsoft community forum (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/xba_modi/sorry-something-went-wrong-give-it-another-try-or/f36aaa4f-e30d-466f-a49e-0d80a8f7a867?tm=1561911439816), but no help so far.

Comment: Minecraft doesn't use the Xbox.com net address, I believe.  Did you try adding https://www.minecraft.net to the list of allowed websites?

Comment: I just tried adding minecraft.net to the list -- no luck. If I can just find what address Xbox Live authenticates thru

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Minecraft works on iOS.  Do you need to sign into the Xbox Live account every time before you use the Minecraft app?  I thought you only need to sign in once and then you can use the app.  You can add app playing limits to the Minecraft app, [this article](https://www.techjunkie.com/ios-12-screen-time-limits-specific-apps/) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I am still fighting this issue. Navigating to settings > Screen time > Content & Privacy Restrictions > Content Restrictions > Web content > and then adding in "live.com" to the list of approved websites solved this issue for me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We love answers to old question. Thanks for joining and pitching in.

Comment: Sadly this didn’t work for me. Add in all Microsoft domains etc. the weird thing is my kids cannot join one another but on my in restricted device I can join either of their worlds. And me hosting they can join my worlds just not when on creates their own world

Answer (score 0):

This has been plaguing my son for over a year I finally sat down to figure it out. 
The sign in is attempting to use a browser to sign in to a website so the authorization website.
At this time **I needed to add the following sites to the allowed web content restrictions to live.com and msauth.net** 
I also added xbox.com and microsoft.com just in case the website changes.

Before I did that he couldn't sign in on his ipad just get a green screen saying ""Sorry, something went wrong. Give it another try, or try on Xbox.com"
even though he could sign in using the xbox app on the ipad.

Comment: I recently had this issue and I had already added the usual Microsoft login redirects. I now had to add login.live.com uniquely. For some reason live.com did was not enough.